# Dynamic grid within a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have a grid which contains dynamically created pairs of textblocks and buttons. I can continue to add these objects infinitely but after they fill the grid, the new pairs are not visible.

I have tried to solve this by putting the grid inside a scrollviewer and each time a new pair is added, increasing the height/maxheight of both the grid and the scrollviewer. But I still cannot see the new elements after the screen is filled.

This is from my .xaml file

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScroll" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="577" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470"> </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

and this is from my .xaml.cs file

```
        List<TextBlock> textblock_list = new List<TextBlock>();
        List<Button> button_list = new List<Button>();
        for(int i = 0; i < classlist.Count(); i++)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb = SetTextBlock(tb, i);
            tb.Text = classlist[i].name;
            textblock_list.Add(tb);
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(textblock_list[i]);

            Button bt = new Button();
            bt = SetButton(bt, i);
            button_list.Add(bt);
            ContentPanel.Children.Add(button_list[i]);
            Grid.SetColumn(bt, i);
        }
```

Any thoughts on a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `Height="577"` from your grid

Comment: That worked really well, thanks! Although, I not sure if I understand why it works. Is it because something in the Grid class automatically adjusts the height to fit the content as long as the height is not set by the programmer?

Comment: Please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and don't forget to mark accepted answer :)